# Path problems w/angular 2, SystemJS, node_modules

Tags: angular, path, gulp, systemjs

I have a small Angular 2.0 app. It runs fine on my machines ;-) It uses SystemJS and I have a gulp build for it. The problem is when I deploy it to a sub-directory it is look at the root directory for node-modules. It should be looking at:

```
example.com/myapp/node_modules
```

but it is looking at

```
example.com/node_modules
```

instead.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",?
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or     no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del('dist/**/*');
});

// TypeScript compile
gulp.task('compile', ['clean', 'copy:libs', 'copy:assets'], function () {
    return gulp
        .src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});

// copy dependencies
gulp.task('copy:libs', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
        'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
        'node_modules/**/*.js',
        'node_modules/**/*.css'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/node_modules'))
});

// copy static assets - i.e. non TypeScript compiled source
gulp.task('copy:assets', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/**/*', 'index.html', 'systemjs.config.js',         '!app/**/*.ts'], { base : './' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('build', ['compile']);
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `sourceRoot="myapp/"` to the tsconfig.json. This option

> Specifies the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files
>   instead of source locations. Use this flag if the sources will be
>   located at run-time in a different location than that at design-time.
>   The location specified will be embedded in the sourceMap to direct the
>   debugger where the source files will be located.